# Tar not preserving extended attributes of 'trusted' namespace

Tags: tar, xattr

### Explanation

I am using tar for creating an archive containing a folder and some of its files have extended attributes.

Including these:

- `trusted.size=5`
- `trusted.test`

I created and extracted the archive this way:

```
sudo tar --xattrs --xattrs-include='trused\.' -cf file.tar archive_folder .
sudo tar --xattrs --xattrs-include='trused\.' -xvf file.tar -C extracted_folder
```

### The problem

After extracting the files I try to view the attributes:

```
sudo getfattr -n trusted.size file
```

But the attributes are always missing. How do I preserve those attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little play with the tar creation and extraction lines, iv'e found that
`tar --xattrs --xattrs-include=*`
Must be used in order to save and extract xattributes

Comment: Thanks for this, the man page clearly says "by default they're all stored", but in practice you must include the --xattrs-include=* for it to work as expected. :-/

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using gnu tar 1.30 and when creating the tarball I only need to set `--xattrs` but when extracting it, I need `--xattrs --xattrs-include='*'`. Can you confirm?

Comment: @josch: I can confirm for tar version Ubuntu20.04/1.30+dfsg-7ubuntu0.20.04.2 (GNU tar 1.30) and for Ubuntu22.04/1.34+dfsg-1build3 (GNU tar 1.34): It is sufficient for creation to add either `--xattrs` or `--xattrs-include='*'`. -- But for extraction you need at least `--xattrs-include='*'`.